# Navigationbar not displaying in UItableviewcontroller in storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uitableview

i created a `UICollectionviewcontroller`  view and  embed a `UINavigationcontroller` then I created one button in navigation bar.Again i created one `UITableviewcontroller` also i embed one `uinavigationcontroller` to it,when i click the button in `UICollectionview` navigation bar it shows the `UITableviewcontroller` up to this point is fine,but after this the navigation bar in `UITableview` controller is not showing at all.please help me

[image: uitableviewcontroller image]

[image]

Comment: Where is the segue between All Books Controller and the Table View?

Comment: not needed i programetically moving

Answer (score 3):

Try this piece of code to set the navbar to not be hidden:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Good luck

Comment: which code? iam using storyboard so i embede a uinavigationcontroller

Comment: Show us the storyboard then in your question

Answer (score 2):

According to apple docs, this won't be showing the navigation controller. In order to show the navigation controller you need to instantiate a navigation controller first, and then load the table view controller as shown below :

```
LTBaseTableViewController *viewController = [[LTBaseTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
[self.window setRootViewController:navigationController];
```

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with this.  Eventually solved by adding a Navigation Controller as defined in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @barryjones solution, you can directly push a table view controller using the navigation controller.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourTableViewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to the above answers, I have also struggled in a similar way with moving programatically between tabs of a UITabBArController.

Most posts I read suggested

```
tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
```

however this would create the situation where the tab bar was no longer visible. 
Eventually solved by adding the following to the class in AppDelegate.swift

```
var tabBarController: UITabBarController?
```

and then also in AppDelegate,  I modified didFinishLaunchingWithOptions as follows:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    tabBarController = window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
    return true
}
```

You can then use the following line anywhere inside your various view controllers

```
tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
```